# Can you insert into a table where a value is a declared variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

Is it possible to do something like this ?

```
INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate)
VALUES(teacherId, "12A1", "trig", "tomorrow")
teacherID = (
        SELECT teacherId
        FROM teacherlogins
        WHERE teacherid = 5
    )
```

I know this query is incorrect, but is it possible to do this another way?

Comment: You can use `INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate) SELECT teacherId, "12A1", "trig", "tomorrow" FROM teacherlogins WHERE teacherid = 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. One is in the comment above from Barbara, using [INSERT...SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate)
SELECT teacherId, '12A1', 'trig', 'tomorrow'
FROM teacherlogins
WHERE teacherid = 5;
```

Here's another using a [scalar subquery operand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/scalar-subqueries.html):

```
INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate)
VALUES((SELECT teacherId FROM teacherlogins WHERE teacherid = 5 LIMIT 1),
    '12A1', 'trig', 'tomorrow')
```

Here's another using a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and [SELECT INTO syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT teacherId INTO @t FROM teacherlogins WHERE teacherid = 5;

INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate)
VALUES(@t, '12A1', 'trig', 'tomorrow');
```

Here's another: :-)

```
INSERT INTO homework(teacherId, class, name, dueDate)
VALUES(5, '12A1', 'trig', 'tomorrow');
```